# How do you remove two same characters and anything between with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove a part of a string between matching '/' characters. For example:

`'/this is/ a sentence' => ' a sentence'`

I have very little experience using regex so not sure how I could go about doing it or if I even need it.

I know I can use substring but wondering how you would or if it is possible to do using regex.

Currently I have

```
const string = '/this is/ a sentence';
const substring = string.substring(4);
```

This is fine but curious on the regex side of things

Comment: Can the string also contain multiple forward slashes like `/test/this is/ a sentence` and what would the expected output be?

Answer (score 1):

Just using `\/[^\/]*\/` regex and replacing it with empty string?

```js
var s = '/this is/ a sentence'
console.log(s + ' --> ' + s.replace(/\/[^\/]*\//g, ''))
```

This regex `\/[^\/]*\/` matches a `/` then any character except a `/` zero or more times then again a `/` and replaces it with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\/.*?\/`

- `\/` - Matches `/`
- `.*?` - Match anything except new line ( lazy mode )

```js
let str = '/this is/ a sentence'

let op = str.replace(/\/.*?\//g,'')

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this regex:

```
var str = "'/this is/ a sentence' => ' a sentence'";
var re = str.replace(/(?!<\")\/[^\*]+\/(?!\")/g,'')
console.log("re: " + re);
```